# Able to decrypt an encrypted text in Java despite changing the encrypted text

Tags: java, encryption, aes, apache-commons

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            String textToEncrypt = "{asdfsad asdf;ls kasdf asdlfjaslfjalksdfjlkadsjflkasfjl;kasj alkdfjaslkfj \r\n" +
                    "asdfjl;asdfjlasdjfdasfjfdosafjadsf \r\n" +
                    "as;ldfjal;ksfjlkdasfjadsf" +
                    "a;ldfjal;ksfjds" +
                    "}";
            String secret = "SOME_SECRET";

        String escapedTextToEncrypt = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(textToEncrypt);
        System.out.println(escapedTextToEncrypt);

        String encryptedText = SomeEncryption.encrypt(escapedTextToEncrypt, secret);

        encryptedText = encryptedText.concat("3asdasfd");  // CHANGING THE ENCRYPTED TEXT!

            System.out.println("Encrypted Text :" + encryptedText);

            System.out.println("Decrypted Text :" + SomeEncryption.decrypt(encryptedText, secret));  // THIS WORKS!!
        }catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am using AES encryption algorithm and apache commons codec.  Curiously, when I append a string to the encrypted text, it is still able to decrypt it with no problems.  Am I missing something here?

More details:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2withHmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

EDIT:

I am using StringEscapeUtils from apache commons lang library.

Comment: If you delete a character or replace one, it will fail as you expect. The fact that it can decrypt it only means that the appended characters are ignored

Comment: You have failed to provide many critical details. Certainly at a minimum the code for `SomeEncryption.encrypt()` would have to be provided to have any chance at answering your question. All I can say is that normally, when you append anything to ciphertext encrypted in this mode you will get a invalid length exception if you append something that isn't a multiple of 16 bytes, and a bad padding exception (with high probability) if it is a multiple of 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer to this question.  If I add any string at the end of the encrypted string then it works.  But if it is inserted in the middle then it fails.

```
encryptedText = new StringBuilder(encryptedText).insert(0, "xyz").toString();
```

The above fails.